# Picture puzzles

Tags: lateral-thinking, visual

What is this image a picture of?

[image: puzzle]

Comment: It's too bad that self-promotion stinks a little bit, because otherwise this is an entertaining and well-designed puzzle.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, and thanks for your responsiveness in editing out the self-promotion, as well as the excellent puzzle. To give you an idea of the expectations on the site (so you don't get such a frosty response in the future), take the [Tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [Help Center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) if you still have questions. [Meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/) is for discussion about the site and its functions; you may find it interesting. Hope to see you post again soon! Happy Puzzling!

Comment: Also, I edited your question to make the puzzle a bit clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Jail on a 3d monopoly board I would guess.

Comment: @oodalgic is this a spam question to attract SE subscribers to your instagram? Answers should be posted **here**.

Comment: @oodalgic I don't personally mind cross promotion but I'm not sure if it is against the rules honestly. You should get to know the workings of this site though if you are going to use it. If the answer is correct you should click the check mark near the upvote/downvote section to accept the correct answer and take the tour https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Some useful guidelines on self-promotion, how to do it, and how not to, [can be found here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/how-not-to-be-a-spammer-redux).